# Orchard disable elements

Tags: c#, orchardcms

I couldn't find any way neither by searching or trying .

I have a few elements on my module (Element1, Element2, Element3) with the same Category which is `Content` .

is there any way to disable Elements dynamically or to restrict user from using it using permissions ?

Comment: `Category` means `Content type`?

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy The Category of the Element `public override string Category => "Content";`

Comment: Ok, layout elements then. Seems like there is no support for permissions, see https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/issues/7345

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy Is there any event when the element is dragged into the Layout container ?

Comment: I'm not an expert on this issue but i think this stuff is client side javascript, so you can't intercept here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ViRuSTriNiTy said, there is currently no way to disable Elements dynamically or restrict them using permissions. There's an open issue for this however here: https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/issues/7345. PR welcome.